# How do I force a Pending pipeline to stop?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I wanted to start using GitLab CI on gitlab.com to deploy my blog. However, I just found out that apparently something triggered an empty pipeline nine months ago that is [still marked as pending](https://gitlab.com/Vinnl/blog/pipelines/3031854) - thus blocking my new, actual pipeline:

[image]

The pipeline contains 0 jobs. Is there a way to force this pipeline to stop?

Comment: Although I'm still interested in how to stop it, apparently it does not actually block newer pipelines. It just took over 1.5 hour to start.